# What is a formal word meaning “paid off”?

Tags: synonyms, formality, phrasal-verbs

I can not think of any way to say *paid off* in a formal way.

> Susan’s speech and struggle during those rough times has _______.

Comment: You can't coordinate nouns whose meanings are in such different fields. Susan’s determination and hard work during those rough times has really paid dividends / brought her her just rewards.

Comment: Can't think of something to exactly fill the blank, but maybe:

Susan's struggle... was vindicated by the quality of her speech

Other possibilities with some rearranging: 'justified', 'ratified', 'ROI' (if you're feeling MBAish), 'confirmed'.

Comment: Susan's speech and struggle during those rough times were rewarded?

Comment: I would say "paid off".

Answer (score 1):

Susan’s speech and struggle during those rough times has ***borne fruit***.

or

Susan’s speech and struggle during those rough times has ***come to fruition***.

Answer (score 0):

been beneficial, been rewarding, check [here](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/paid_off.html) for more

Comment: We're looking for well written answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you edit your post to explain how it answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

Susan’s speech and struggle during those rough times has been proved **advantageous**

Susan's speech and struggle during those rough times has been **recompensed**

I advise you to keep your vocabulary simple, however. In that case, perhaps use **"rewarded".**